# MySQL: in list of rows find a proper row using given value

Tags: mysql

I have a table called discounts

```
Field        Type 
id           int(11) NOT NULL
resort_id    int(11) NOT NULL
count_from   int(11) NULL
count_to     int(11) NULL
discount     varchar(255) NULL
```

And i have rows like below:

> ```
>  
>   id |product_id |count_from |count_to |discount
>     1|8          |0          |30       |22
>     2|8          |31         |60       |12
> ```

When i am getting 27 as a input i should retrieve the first row (id:1). Suppose if my input is 33 i should retrieve 2 row(id:2).

How to write a mysql query?

Regards,
Prabhu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM discounts
WHERE 27 BETWEEN count_from AND count_to

SELECT *
FROM discounts
WHERE 33 BETWEEN count_from AND count_to
```